# how to write code that capture shut down event with jna?

Tags: java, jna

I want to write a java application that hides in system tray and measures bandwidth traffic.
I want before the PC shutdowns, to save traffic size to file.
I use `shutdownHook` in `java` but it does not work.
How to write code with `JNA` to call save function in my java code before PC shuts down?

Comment: The shutdown hook is not for PC shutdown, it is for the shutdown of the JVM. And it will only work if the JVM is shutdown, not in the case of PC shutdown.

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: windows os platform

Comment: But if the os is shut down then in turn the JVM gets shut down too =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47933334/2979435) do what you want, anyway for your case I suggest just create a Interval task that calculates and save that data because you must to have in mind that if a unexpected behavior like the power is gone or blue screen happen then you will lost data because the shutdown hook will not be called.

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("calculating and saving traffic");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
}
```